# How to resolve non-nullable error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter development and  I'm trying to implement a category page where the data will load from a json file. But I'm getting null safety error"**The non-nullable variable 'categories' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression.**" while creating the class. Please find the below codes for your reference and help to resolve.

There are two dart files one is category_models.dart and another is homecategories.dart

Thanks in advance.

**Category_model.dart**

```dart
    import 'dart:convert';

    class CategoryModel { 
    static List<Category> categories;
    }

    class Category {
    final int id;
    final String name;
    final String image;
    Category({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.image,
    });

    Category copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? name,
    String? image,
    }) {
    return Category(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      name: name ?? this.name,
      image: image ?? this.image,
    );
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'image': image,
    };
    }

    factory Category.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Category(
      id: map['id'],
      name: map['name'],
      image: map['image'],
    );
    }

    String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

    factory Category.fromJson(String source) =>
      Category.fromMap(json.decode(source));

    @override
    String toString() => 'Category(id: $id, name: $name, image: $image)';

    @override
    bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return other is Category &&
        other.id == id &&
        other.name == name &&
        other.image == image;
    }

    @override
    int get hashCode => id.hashCode ^ name.hashCode ^ image.hashCode;
    }
```

**Categoroes.dart**

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:citimart/models/category_model.dart';

    class HomeCategories extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _HomeCategoriesState createState() => _HomeCategoriesState();
    }

    class _HomeCategoriesState extends State<HomeCategories> {
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
    }

    loadData() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    final categoryJson =
        await rootBundle.loadString("assets/files/categories.json");
    final decodedData = jsonDecode(categoryJson);
    var categoriesData = decodedData["categories"];
    CategoryModel.categories = List.from(categoriesData)
        .map<Category>((category) => Category.fromMap(category))
        .toList();
    setState(() {});
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Please add the exact error to your question.

Comment: I have added the exact error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must initialize the `CategoryModel.categories` variable, since this variable has been defined as a `non-nullable` it cant be left uninitialized as this is `null`.

You should update the model class and set an initial value for the categories, for example

```dart
class CategoryModel { 
    static List<Category> categories = List.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `static List<Category> categories;` is a `List<Category>` type. Since its non-nullable, the value it holds can *never* be null. So from the initialization you need to supply a value.

You can solve this in a few ways. The easiest would be to give an initial value:

```
static List<Category> categories = [];
```

Other ways to handle this without giving an initial value would be to make the variable nullable, or marking it with a late initialization keyword. To read more of this, check the oficial documentation [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety).